# MVC 4 Dropdownlist formatting Mobile App

Tags: c#, css, html, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile-application

New to MVC 4.

I am just starting out with a test project. I have managed to bind data to a html5 dropdownlist successfully.

My question is why my dd renders as an ugly grey/white box and not as a sexy white on blue as with the other controls.

in the screen-shot I have attached the blue seems to be under the ugly one.

Anyone know how to manipulate this with an example?

I looked at the CSS and had a fiddle, but can't seem to pin point the connection to the html5 control.

[image]

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "My Blah";
        List<SelectListItem> Languages = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Languages.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "English",
            Value = "1",
            Selected = true
        });
        Languages.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "русский",
            Value = "2",
        });
        ViewData.Add("Languages", Languages);
        return View();
    }

@using Resources;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("Languages")

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(@HomeResource.About, "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(@HomeResource.Contact, "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS is untouched

EDITED CODE

Comment: I just tried this in IE and Chrome ... seems Opera does not render but the others do. Opera mobile doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You must have messed up something with the CSS. Hard to tell without you seeing your code.

But here are some steps you could try to set things up and you get you started:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Application using the Mobile template
2. Add a view model:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       public string Value { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
       {
           get
           {
               return new[]
               {
                   new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                   new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                   new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Update the HomeController to pass the view model to the view:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View(new MyViewModel());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Inside the corresponding view render the dropdown (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

   ```
   @model MyViewModel

   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value, Model.Items)

   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
   </ul>
   ```
5. Run the application and get the desired output:

[image]